# Controlling textbox height in a Java Swing layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a form, and when it renders using `pack`, the textboxes have a nice default height. But when I resize it - or in this case, if I override `getPreferredSize` to make it larger on startup - the textboxes resize proportionally.

I keep going in circles trying to understand the layout manager classes... the related questions that are coming up seem like they're really close, but I'm just not following them!

In the class below, if I comment out the `getPreferredSize` overload, the textboxes are sized by the system to be "just right". Add `getPreferredSize` back, or resize manually, and the textbox proportions expand/contract with the form. There's got to be something simple I'm missing!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class TestTextBox extends JFrame {

   private JTextField jtfRate = new JTextField();//jtfAnnualInterestRate
   private JButton jbtComputeLoan = new JButton("Compute Sentence");

   // Constructor buids the panel
   public TestTextBox() {
      // a panel with the fields
      JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2));

      p1.add(new JLabel("Annual Interest Rate"));
      p1.add(jtfRate);

      p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("This is a border with enough text that I want to see it"));

      // a panel with the button
      JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
      p2.add(jbtComputeLoan);

      // Put the panels on the frame
      add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }   

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      // This will help Pack to pack it up better
      return new Dimension(600, 300);
   }   

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestTextBox jailCell = new TestTextBox();
      jailCell.pack(); // Arrange controls compactly based on their properties
      jailCell.setTitle("Calculate your Sentence");
      jailCell.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // sure, center it, whatever
      jailCell.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      jailCell.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Obviously, this is a case for a GUI layout tool. But this isn't production code, this is a Java class in which I'm trying my best to learn *why* it works - that way I'll know what the GUI tools are doing.

**Update:** Thanks to the answer I got, I was able to figure out the basics of the GridBag. It seems pretty closely related to HTML `<table>`s. It took much longer than it should have, mostly because I kept forgetting `, c);` to apply the `GridBagConstraints` to the control! Here's a sample of what the relatively simple add above turned into:

```
  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 0;
  p1.add(new JLabel("Annual Interest Rate"), c);
  c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.gridx = 1;
  c.gridy = 0;
  c.weightx = 0.25;
  p1.add(jtfRate, c);
```

Comment: Can i know what ide are you using?

Comment: @NiteshVerma I'm using jGRASP, at least at the moment. Its charming lack of intellisense, though, is starting to give me a headache.

Comment: You can try Netbeans because i personally use it for desktop application development as it is very robust and effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of `GridLayout` is to provide each component with equal amounts of available space.  This means, as you make the component larger, they will get bigger, as you make it smaller, the will get smaller.

You could use a `GridBagLayout` instead, which will allow you to layout your components in a grid pattern but control how much of the cell they should occupy...

Take a look at [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details...

Comment: That looks like a good resource, thanks! A lot of other discussions on the site tend to describe GridBagLayout as the spawn of the devil, though...

Comment: GridBagLayout is by far one of the most complex layout managers in the JDK, but is one of the most flexible